# memory that not release in another scope in QList

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a very very simple problem.

Why can the following code free memory,

```cpp
QList<double *>rubberList ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)
{
    rubberList.append(new double);
    delete rubberList[i];
}
```

but the following can't?

```cpp
QList<double *>rubberList ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)
{
    rubberList.append(new double);
}
for(int j = 0 ; j < 1000000 ; j++)
{
    delete rubberList[j];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what makes you conclude that the second instance is not freeing the memory? Also, please specify which programming language you're using.

Comment: Are you *sure* you can apply `delete` to a `QList` element? That would mean you bypass the internals of the `QList` implementation. You first need to remove the element from the `QList`. I think you want to use [QList removeAt(i)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#removeAt) before the delete.

Comment: it is very simple, if execute sample cods you can see that when try to remove out off constrained block never remove completely memory that allocated, but if remove in constrained block completely remove all memory that allocated .
why ? !!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are probably using a simple tool like taskmanager or top to see memory usage at OS level. But this includes the freespace on the heap within the application that will be used to satisfy future memory requests. Sample one never allocates more then one double so has lower peak memory usage and because of that has also less freespace on its heap resulting in a smaller size at the OS level.